# Git for Windows opens a separate console every time I try to run git.exe?

Tags: windows, git

I have added C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd to my path environment variable.

All git commands run successfully but also open a new console which displays git's help.

Running git.exe directly also opens a separate console.

This is quite annoying as I see a popup every time I try to run a git command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` to your `PATH`, not the `cmd` folder.

That should be enough to avoid the new console to popup every time.

Try the same (bin only to PATH) with a simple [`PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20150319.7z`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20150319/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20150319.7z) uncompressed anywhere you want.

---

Note: Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) offers a [`headless-git.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76909718/6309), a non-console program that does not pop up any window.
That can be an alternative to test out here.

Comment: @rlesias I have edited the answer: try the same with the PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20150319.7z archive.

Comment: this the version I use. I have tried to reinstall Git without result

Comment: @rlesias I know. Try, just for testing, to uncompress  PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20150319.7z and add the bin folder to your PATH. No setup required.

Comment: sorry, I was too fast. It works with the Portable version. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted your answer but still would like to understand why it doesn't work with the standard version.

Comment: @rlesias Not sure: a similar issue was reported in https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/316. I never use the setup myself, always the archive. Plus, msysgit is no longer actively maintained. All the work is for Git 2.3 now: https://gist.github.com/shiftkey/add6975be2687d8731ae (Git for Windows: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)